# I need to convert VB.net Code to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to convert this code to c#. I have problem in line 8. 
Public Class Database

```
Public Function GetCourses(StudentID As Integer) As List(Of Course)

    Dim xEntity As New MyLearningEntities
    Dim xList As New List(Of Course)
    Dim xStudent As Student

    xStudent = (From x In xEntity.Students.Include("Courses") Select x Where x.StudentID = StudentID).FirstOrDefault

    If xStudent IsNot Nothing Then
        Return xStudent.Courses.ToList
    Else
        Return xList
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Please at least post your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [link](http://converter.telerik.com/) to convert from C# to VB.Net and vice-versa

```
public List<Course> GetCourses(int StudentID)
{
    MyLearningEntities xEntity = new MyLearningEntities();
    List<Course> xList = new List<Course>();
    Student xStudent = default(Student);

    xStudent = (from x in xEntity.Students.Include("Courses") where x.StudentID == StudentID select x).FirstOrDefault();

    if (xStudent != null)
        return xStudent.Courses.ToList;
    else
        return xList;
}
```

[image]